# How can I disable `cudf` in certain part of my code?

Tags: python, pandas, numba, jit, cudf

I run the code below with `python3.10 -m cudf.pandas my_py.py`. I realized that `cudf` use `numba` for `cudf.apply` on `UDF` w/o `@numba.autojit(nopython=True)` decorator, and hence the code below with object `datetime` cannot be processed by `cudf`.

Is it possible that I can **disable `cudf`** in this part of the code? I tried `df_tmp = my_df.to_pandas().apply(g_a,ax=1)`, but it said `my_df` is a `pd.DF` and had no `to_pandas()` function. I further printed the type of object `my_df`, and it returned  `<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>`

```
def gzpd_apply(my_df00):
  # some code
  t_prelude = '08:30:00'
  t_prev = datetime.strptime(t_prelude, '%H:%M:%S')
  # some code

# some code
print(type(my_df))
df_tmp = my_df.apply(gzpd_apply,axis=1)
# some code
```

Here are the package versions I'm using `numpy==1.24.3 pandas==1.5.3 Cython==3.0.6 swifter==1.3.4 numba==0.57.1`

The dataframe `my_df` looks like:

```
index | YMH          | name  |     time   | <other fields>
000   | '2020-01-01' | 'Tom' | '09:05:00' | ...
001   | '2022-01-01' | 'John'| '09:05:00' | ...
002   | '2023-05-01' | 'Bob' | '08:05:00' | ...
```

Currently the code has this error:

```
numba.core.errors.TypingError: Failed in cuda mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Untyped global name 'datetime': Cannot determine Numba type of <class 'type'>
```

I know why there is such an error. I wonder how I can bypass it.

---

To add an example (2024.1.5)

I was able to create a toy example to reproduce the error.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import swifter
import sys, os
#import cudf

def gzpd_apply(my_df00):
    col_df_1 = [x for x in my_df00.index if '_1' in x]
    if my_df00[col_df_1].isnull().sum()>0:
        return np.nan
    if my_df00['time']==my_df00['time_1']:
        my_df00['time_1'] = (datetime.strptime(my_df00['time_1'], '%H:%M:%S')+timedelta(minutes=5)).strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    return my_df00.rename(index=dict({x:x for x in my_df00.index})).transpose() if (my_df00 is not None) else np.nan

def main():
    my_df = pd.DataFrame(data={'YMH': ['2019-01-02', '2018-01-02', '2019-05-02', '2020-01-02', '2021-01-02'], 'name': ['albert', 'alex', 'alice', 'ben', 'bob'], 'time': ['09:00:00', '09:20:00', '08:00:00', '07:00:00', '09:30:00']})
    my_df = pd.concat([my_df for i in range(5)], axis=0)
    my_df['YMH'] = np.random.permutation(my_df['YMH'].values)
    my_df['time'] = np.random.permutation(my_df['time'].values)
    my_df = my_df.sort_values(by=['YMH', 'time', 'name'], inplace=False).reset_index(drop=True,inplace=False)
    my_df = pd.concat([my_df, my_df.shift(1).rename(columns=dict({x:x+'_1' for x in my_df.columns}))],axis=1)
# data generated ------------------------------------------------------
    #df_tmp = my_df.apply(gzpd_apply,axis=1) # !! w/o swifter, the code works fine
    df_tmp = my_df.swifter.apply(gzpd_apply,axis=1) # !! w/ swifter, the code returns error.
# no error below -------------------------------------------------------
    df_tmp = df_tmp.T.dropna().reset_index(drop=True)
    df_tmp = pd.concat([r for r in df_tmp],axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)
    df_tmp = df_tmp.transpose()
    df_tmp.rename(columns=dict({i: my_df.columns[i] for i in range(len(my_df.columns))}), inplace=True)
    pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)
    print(df_tmp)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

In the above toy example, if I don't use `swifter`, the code works fine. When I use `swifter`, the code returns the aformentioned `numba.core.errors`. Note that in my *original project*, the `numba` error comes **regardless of `swifter`**.

The above toy example has the following error (the numba error comes in the middle):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/swifter/swifter.py", line 427, in apply
    tmp_df = func(sample, *args, **kwds)
  File "my_cudf.py", line 10, in gzpd_apply
    col_df_1 = [x for x in my_df00.index if '_1' in x]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/cudf/utils/utils.py", line 242, in __iter__
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: Int64Index object is not iterable. Consider using `.to_arrow()`, `.to_pandas()` or `.values_host` if you wish to iterate over the values.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/cudf/core/indexed_frame.py", line 2360, in _apply
    kernel, retty = _compile_or_get(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/nvtx/nvtx.py", line 115, in inner
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/cudf/core/udf/utils.py", line 269, in _compile_or_get
    kernel, scalar_return_type = kernel_getter(frame, func, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/cudf/core/udf/row_function.py", line 143, in _get_row_kernel
    scalar_return_type = _get_udf_return_type(row_type, func, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/nvtx/nvtx.py", line 115, in inner
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/cudf/core/udf/utils.py", line 89, in _get_udf_return_type
    ptx, output_type = cudautils.compile_udf(func, compile_sig)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/cudf/utils/cudautils.py", line 126, in compile_udf
    ptx_code, return_type = cuda.compile_ptx_for_current_device(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/numba/cuda/compiler.py", line 319, in compile_ptx_for_current_device
    return compile_ptx(pyfunc, sig, debug=debug, lineinfo=lineinfo,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/numba/core/compiler_lock.py", line 35, in _acquire_compile_lock
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/numba/cuda/compiler.py", line 289, in compile_ptx
    cres = compile_cuda(pyfunc, return_type, args, debug=debug,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/numba/core/compiler_lock.py", line 35, in _acquire_compile_lock
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/numba/cuda/compiler.py", line 230, in compile_cuda
    cres = compiler.compile_extra(typingctx=typingctx,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/numba/core/compiler.py", line 762, in compile_extra
    return pipeline.compile_extra(func)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/numba/core/compiler.py", line 460, in compile_extra
    return self._compile_bytecode()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/numba/core/compiler.py", line 528, in _compile_bytecode
    return self._compile_core()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/numba/core/compiler.py", line 507, in _compile_core
    raise e
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/numba/core/compiler.py", line 494, in _compile_core
    pm.run(self.state)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/numba/core/compiler_machinery.py", line 368, in run
    raise patched_exception
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/numba/core/compiler_machinery.py", line 356, in run
    self._runPass(idx, pass_inst, state)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/numba/core/compiler_lock.py", line 35, in _acquire_compile_lock
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/numba/core/compiler_machinery.py", line 311, in _runPass
    mutated |= check(pss.run_pass, internal_state)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/numba/core/compiler_machinery.py", line 273, in check
    mangled = func(compiler_state)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/numba/core/typed_passes.py", line 110, in run_pass
    typemap, return_type, calltypes, errs = type_inference_stage(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/numba/core/typed_passes.py", line 86, in type_inference_stage
    infer.build_constraint()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/numba/core/typeinfer.py", line 1039, in build_constraint
    self.constrain_statement(inst)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/numba/core/typeinfer.py", line 1386, in constrain_statement
    self.typeof_assign(inst)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/numba/core/typeinfer.py", line 1461, in typeof_assign
    self.typeof_global(inst, inst.target, value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/numba/core/typeinfer.py", line 1561, in typeof_global
    typ = self.resolve_value_type(inst, gvar.value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/numba/core/typeinfer.py", line 1482, in resolve_value_type
    raise TypingError(msg, loc=inst.loc)
numba.core.errors.TypingError: Failed in cuda mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Untyped global name 'datetime': Cannot determine Numba type of <class 'type'>

File "my_cudf.py", line 14:
def gzpd_apply(my_df00):
    <source elided>
    if my_df00['time']==my_df00['time_1']:
        my_df00['time_1'] = (datetime.strptime(my_df00['time_1'], '%H:%M:%S')+timedelta(minutes=5)).strftime('%H:%M:%S')
        ^


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/cudf/pandas/__main__.py", line 91, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/cudf/pandas/__main__.py", line 87, in main
    runpy.run_path(args.args[0], run_name="__main__")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 289, in run_path
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "my_cudf.py", line 37, in <module>
    main()
  File "my_cudf.py", line 27, in main
    df_tmp = my_df.swifter.apply(gzpd_apply,axis=1) # apply
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/swifter/swifter.py", line 436, in apply
    timed = timeit.timeit(wrapped, number=N_REPEATS)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/timeit.py", line 234, in timeit
    return Timer(stmt, setup, timer, globals).timeit(number)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/timeit.py", line 178, in timeit
    timing = self.inner(it, self.timer)
  File "<timeit-src>", line 6, in inner
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/swifter/swifter.py", line 339, in wrapped
    self._obj.iloc[self._SAMPLE_INDEX].apply(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/nvtx/nvtx.py", line 115, in inner
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/cudf/core/dataframe.py", line 4488, in apply
    return self._apply(func, _get_row_kernel, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/contextlib.py", line 79, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/nvtx/nvtx.py", line 115, in inner
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/cudf/core/indexed_frame.py", line 2364, in _apply
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: user defined function compilation failed.
```

---

Update (2024.1.8)

I modified the above code to (with proper import):

```
with disable_module_accelerator():
   df_tmp = my_df.swifter.apply(gzpd_apply,axis=1) # !! w/ swifter, the code returns error.
```

Only one line of code is included into the with-context. It throws the same error. Note that if I don't include any `cudf` related code/command, the above code snippet runns correctly regardless of `swifter`.

Comment: When using cudf.pandas, there is no `to_pandas` method on the dataframe (since it's acting as if it's a pandas object). If the UDF can't run on the GPU it should fallback to the CPU (absent a bug). Can you share a minimal, complete, reproducible example that generates the error?

Comment: @NickBecker I created a toy example reproducing the `numba.core.errors.TypingError` with the "help" of `swifter`, although in my original code, the `numba` error came regardless of `swifter`

Comment: Thanks. It looks like using Swifter with cudf.pandas creates a scenario in which the exception raised during a failed JIT compilation of a Numba CUDA function isn't properly bubbled up, so no fallback happens if the function can't run on the GPU. I'll file a cuDF Github issue to track this. As a note, you might be interested in this blog post about [crafting minimal bug reports](https://matthewrocklin.com/minimal-bug-reports.html).

Comment: For now, you can select selectively disable the accelerator [like this](https://github.com/rapidsai/cudf/issues/14692#issuecomment-1873046122). This functionality is not currently documented and is still subject to change, but may be useful in this specific setting.

Comment: @NickBecker I tried `disable_module_accelerator` as described in OP. I feel the disable command did not take into effect, and the very same error comes again. Did I use the module incorrectly?